# Open activity already open from notification

Tags: android, android-notifications, android-alarms

I create an alarm with notification, but when I open MainActivity through the notification, another MainActivity is open over the previous and if I close MainActivity there is another MainActivity under.

This is the code of my BroadcastReceiver:

```
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
    {

        Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
        PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context,
                        0, notificationIntent,
                        PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);

         NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
                    new NotificationCompat.Builder(context);
         mBuilder.setContentIntent(contentIntent)
                    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
                    .setContentTitle("E' ora di colazione!")
                    .setContentText("Cosa c'è per colazione?")
                    .setAutoCancel(true);


                NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
                mNotificationManager.notify(1, mBuilder.build());


    }   

}
```

Comment: you want to keep only one activity?

Comment: Did you try `android:launchMode="singleTop" ` or `android:launchMode="singleInstance"` in Manifest?

Comment: @NoName yes just one activity

Comment: @KonradKrakowiak I tried android:launchMode="singleTop", and the app crash

Answer (score 1):

Add this **android:launchMode="singleTask"** in your activity tag of `Menifest.xml`

@Override `onNewIntent` in your Activity class.

Your class will got new intent in onNewIntent() and proceed whatever you want.

```
@Override
    protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {

        super.onNewIntent(intent);
    }
```

Comment: It works but there is a point in my application in which I call a new Intent:       `Intent myIntent = new Intent(getActivity(), MainActivity.class);
                         getActivity().startActivity(myIntent); 
                         getActivity().finish();` in this point my app crash

Answer (score 0):

Update your intent creation code

add the following flag to the intent `FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT`

```
Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
notificationIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT);
```

Answer (score 0):

I've find a solution using `notificationIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);`

```
@Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
    {

        Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
        notificationIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
        PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context,
                        0, notificationIntent,
                        PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);

         NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
                    new NotificationCompat.Builder(context);
         mBuilder.setContentIntent(contentIntent)
                    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
                    .setContentTitle("E' ora di colazione!")
                    .setContentText("Cosa c'è per colazione?")
                    .setAutoCancel(true);


                NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
                mNotificationManager.notify(1, mBuilder.build());


    }
```